# Runtime permission dialog is not showing Android 7.1

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to init a service,it needs permission of `READ_PHONE_STATE`.I declare it and apply dynamically.The callback function has been rewritten.However, the virtual machine don't pop a dialog box of requesting permission.

The code reads as follows.

Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Apply dynamically:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1);
```

Please help me. Be deeply grateful.

Comment: give code of `requestPermissions` method

Comment: Sorry, I just started learning, I don't quite follow you. Please describe the details in more detail.

Comment: @CWing, please edit your question adding the content of the requestPermissions function

Answer (score 0):

Use below functions for checking runtime permissions in onCreate() method:

```
   checkPermission();
   requestPermission();
```

and Functions are:

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {
    return ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_PHONE_STATE ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_SMS);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SMS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access and sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                                    REQUEST_SMS);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a try

Comment: It tell me "Permission Denied, You cannot access and sms."

Comment: which version are u using of android?

Comment: Nexus 5x  x86_64 Android 7.11(Google APIs)

Comment: I have sent it as an answer below.

Comment: Write my answer code in splash screen.It will ask u for permissions.

Comment: I inserted your answer into my code, but the virtual machine didn't ask me permission

Comment: what's your targetsdkversion in build.gradle file

Comment: The  targetsdkversion is 25.

Comment: Remove this line........ requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},1);

Comment: The result remains

Comment: I wonder if I have any problem with IDE configuration, but I don't know where to start to find the problem

Comment: Although ,my problem is not solved,I am very grateful to you for you spend time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```css
import static android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;


public class CoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnAccountListener {

    boolean init_state;
    AccountApi accountApi;
    UiHandler uiHandle=new UiHandler(this);


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Message msg=new Message();
        msg.what=MsgCode.STATE_LOGIN_START;
        uiHandle.sendMessage(msg);
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},1);
//        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//        boolean permission = (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
//                pm.checkPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE", "com.example.asus.tl"));
//        if (permission) {
//            Log.d("permission","yes");
//        }else {
//            Log.d("permission","no");
//        }

        checkPermission();
        requestPermission();

        init_state=API.init(this);
        Log.d("API.init",init_state+"");
        Log.d("service",isServiceRunning()+"");

        Thread getAccountThread=new Thread(delayInitApi);
        getAccountThread.start();
    }





    private boolean isServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.algebra.sdk.Controller".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        return ( this.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), SEND_SMS ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private int checkSelfPermission(Context applicationContext, String sendSms) {
    return 1;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CoreActivity.this, new String[]{SEND_SMS}, 1);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access and sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SEND_SMS)) {
//                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{SEND_SMS},
                                                        1);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

in your Manifest

Comment: Thank u.Now he no longer has permission to apply for the wrong number, but a new error has occurred. dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could tell me the principle of the problem just now

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.asus.tl-2/base.apk", zipfile"/data/app/com.example.asus.tl2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",zip file"/..."/data/app/com.example.asus.tl2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.asus.tl-2/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libamr-codec.so"

Comment: Please forgive my format, these contents are linked together. I've been asking questions second times here, so I'm not familiar with how to write beautiful formats